# Regular expression for capturing all text starting at one pattern and ending at another

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am scraping text data off a pdf using python. There is a common pattern that contains the data I need that begins with a numerical pattern and ends with a string pattern. I need to capture all the text, including the patterns using a regular expression.

I have a regular expression that works when I import the data by going pdf to txt and reading the text in. When I use PyPDF2 to extract the text from the pdf pages, the regular expression fails.

The data stream looks like this

```
Filed: 8/21/2022\nEntered:  10/21/2022\nDischarged:  01/23/2023\nClosed: 01/30/2023\n17-55018-   \nQRTbk 7 Windows PC\n OS:xxx\nRole: AdminHubertson
```

The start point is the `17-55018-` string which I have a regex that works:

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-
```

The end point is the `Role: Admin` which is unique enough to compile.

I have tried a number of capture methods using lookaheads to get the text I need. These methods I have tested on regex101 and they work but I cannot get them to work

Some patterns I have tried:

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-\s(\n(?!Role)(.*))*Role: Admin
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-\.(.*?)Role: Admin
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{5}-.*(?=Role).*Role: Admin
```

Comment: Did you use the `re.DOTALL` flag so that `.*` will match multiple lines?

Comment: Trying that now and finally re.search is returning something. Not getting all the way to Role: Admin but I can mess around with my regex now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
\d{2}\-\d{5}.*?Role:\sAdmin
```

Comment: It´s a pleasure to help you @DataNoob! Good luck.